# How do you construct probability spaces of sequences of events from probability spaces of individual events?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In problem 1.8 of Introduction to Probability 2nd ed. by Bertsekas and Tsitsiklis you are asked to confirm a winning strategy for an interesting chess tournament.

You are to play only three opponents in any order of your choosing, and **you know the probability of beating each opponent**. If you beat two consecutive players, you win.

After consulting a solution, I found it difficult to reason about the probability space in question, how to conceive of taking unions and intersections of the event sets, and how to reason about the probability of an event set given the probability of beating a single opponent.

It seems the collection of winning events are composed of sequences of the form $(W_1, W_2)$, $(L_1, W_2, W_3)$, while the collection of losing events are composed of sequences of the form $(W_1, L_2, L_3)$, $(W_1, L_2, W_3)$, $(L_1, L_2, L_3)$, $(L_1, L_2, W_3)$ where $W_i$ denotes a win against opponent $i$, and $L_i$ denotes losing to opponent $i$ (note that the index refers to the position of the opponent in the sequence, but that can be any one of the three players you are playing against). It would be these sequences that comprise the probability space, and thus we must be able to construct probabilities for them, but we only really understand how to interpret the probability of beating or losing to a particular opponent. That is, how are $P(W_1)$ and $P(W_2)$ related to $P(W_1, W_2)$? $P(W_1, W_2)$ doesn't seem to be $P(W_1 \bigcap W_2)$ because the singletons $\{W_1\}$ and $\{W_2\}$ are not elements of the chess tournament space. How do I define an intersection or union of two sequences from the chess tournament space?

The solution acknowledges that the probability of a win is the probability of "winning in the second round, **and** either winning in the first **or** losing in the first **and** winning in the second round." This is taken to be $$P[W_2 \bigcap [W_1 \bigcup (L_1 \bigcap W_3)]] = P(W_2)P[W_1\bigcup (L_1\bigcap W_3)] = P(W_2)[P(W_1) + (1-P(W_1))P(W_3)]$$
where it is assumed beating an opponent has nothing to do with ordering and thus the events are independent. Optimization of this probability results from placing the weakest opponent in slot 2. It doesn't seem consistent with the true probability space under consideration (sequences of games). There must be a way to construct the tournament event space by extending the individual game spaces in such a way that set unions and intersection are formally defined and the solution is placed under firmer mathematical ground.